# Does user id(sub) change or not in keycloak?

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid-connect

I have tried several times these days, the user id(sub) is same.

But I am not sure (e.g. some months later?) as I didn't find any documentation related to that, can anyone give me a hand, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the subject will not change for a user. The entire point is that that ID must be stable and uniquely identify an account.